# Java large size array random generation of integers from 0 to 99 and calculating sum and average of integers between 25 and 75 inclusive

Tags: java, arrays, sum, integer, average

I created a large array of random integers and calculated sum and average of odd integers between 25 and 75 (inclusive). So far the program is running but the result its giving is too long in other words its showing every addition and average step individually how can i displayed the result after all calculations are completed

```
    import java.util.*;


    class ArraySUMAVG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("calculating Arrays...");

    String name = "os.name";

    System.out.println("Name: " + System.getProperty(name));

    String version = "os.version";

    System.out.println("Version: " + System.getProperty(version));

    String architecture = "os.arch";

    System.out.println("Arch: " + System.getProperty(architecture));

    String[] array = new String[1312500];

    int size = array.length;

    System.out.println("Size of the Array is: " + array.length);

    System.out.println("Total number of system cores(processors): " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    System.out.println("The Size of Array is divisible by the size of Processors(1312500/4): " + array.length/Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    Random r = new Random();

    int[] values = new int[1312500];    

    int sumarray=0; 

    int CountD=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    int randomint = r.nextInt(100);

    values[i] = randomint;

    if((values[i]%3 == 0) && (values[i] >=25 && values[i] <=75)){

    int Sum = sumarray += values[i];

    CountD++;

    int Average = sumarray/CountD;

    System.out.println("The Sum is: " + Sum);

    System.out.println("The Average is: " + Average);

    }
    }
    }
    }
```

the result is:

```
    The Sum is: 11411853

    The Average is: 51

    The Sum is: 11411901

    The Average is: 51

    The Sum is: 11411961

    The Average is: 51

    The Sum is: 11412033

    The Average is: 51

    The Sum is: 11412069

    The Average is: 51

    The Sum is: 11412123

    The Average is: 51
```

how can i cut this calculations

Comment: you just instantiated an array of zeros, you create a random class but it is never used. What is your expected outcome, also you should properly format your code. Also odd means not divisible by two, not that it is divisible by 3 ?

Comment: Eduardo Dennis not help full

Answer (score 0):

Your whole array is initialized to 0, it never is greater than 25.

This program calculates the sum and average of ODD integers between 25 and 75

```
class ArraySUMAVG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int []num = new int[40000];
        int count = 0;
        int sumArr = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<num.length ; i++){
            num[i] = i;
            if(i>=25 && i<=75 && i%2!=0){
                sumArr += num[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Summary is: " + sumArr + " and Average is: " + (sumArr*1.0)/count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anurag Awasthi your coding worked but What should i do if i want to divide the program in different Threads and assign threads to different processors (SPMD, Flynn's Taxonomy

Comment: You want to split this 'Calculating sum n average' work among multiple threads, right? 1st thread to check first 10,000 elements of array and 2nd thread to, from num[10000] to num[20000] n so on

Comment: yes exactly and also assign threads to procressors and show how they are working and what is their status

Answer (score 0):

if this condition is not met:

```
    if((nums[i]%3 == 0) && (nums[i] >=25 && nums[i] <=75))
    {
        sumarray += nums[i];
        CountD++;
    }
```

`CountD` never gets incremented. So for that matter,
`(sumarray/CountD)` is actually `(sumarray/0)` which is undefine.